# How to apply Duhamel's Integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I found one good procedure for solving the simple system of two equations with reducing on Duhamel's Integral, but I have problem to apply the same procedure on system with four equations. Let's see first what I already did. If we have the system

$$ \left(\text{k1} \text{S1}(t)+\text{k1} \text{S2}(t)+\text{m1} \text{S1}''(t)+\text{m1} \text{S2}''(t)=\text{f1}(t)\right) $$ $$\left(\text{$\alpha $1} \left(\text{k2} \text{S1}(t)+\text{m2} \text{S1}''(t)\right)+\text{$\alpha $2} \left(\text{k2} \text{S2}(t)+\text{m2} \text{S2}''(t)\right)=\text{f2}(t)\right) $$

My goal was to found $\text{S1}(t)+\text{S2}(t)$ and $\text{$\alpha $1} \text{S1}(t)+\text{$\alpha $2} \text{S2}(t)$

First I wrote the system in the following form $$\sum _{i=1}^2 \text{Si}''(t)+\frac{\text{k1} \text{Si}(t)}{\text{m1}}=\frac{\text{f1}(t)}{\text{m1}}$$ 
$$\sum _{i=1}^2 \text{$\alpha $i} \left(\frac{\text{k2} \text{Si}(t)}{\text{m2}}+\text{Si}''(t)\right)=\frac{\text{f2}(t)}{\text{m2}}$$

and solutions are known as Duhamel's Integral

$$\text{S1}(t)+\text{S2}(t)=\sum _{i=1}^2 \frac{\int_0^t \text{Yi}(s) \sin \left(\sqrt{\frac{\text{ki}}{\text{mi}}} (t-s)\right) \, ds}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{ki}}{\text{mi}}}}$$
$$\text{$\alpha $1} \text{S1}(t)+\text{$\alpha $2} \text{S2}(t)=\sum _{i=1}^2 \frac{\text{$\alpha $i} \int_0^t \text{Yi}(s) \sin \left(\sqrt{\frac{\text{ki}}{\text{mi}}} (t-s)\right) \, ds}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{ki}}{\text{mi}}}}$$

where

$$\text{Y1}=\frac{\text{$\alpha $2} \text{m1} \text{f1}(t)-\text{m2} \text{f2}(t)}{\text{$\alpha $2}-\text{$\alpha $1}}$$
$$\text{Y2}=\frac{\text{$\alpha $1} \text{m1} \text{f1}(t)-\text{m2} \text{f2}(t)}{\text{$\alpha $1}-\text{$\alpha $2}}$$

The problem is how to find solution in the presented way with Duhamel's Integral but for this system with 4 eqs.

$$\text{k1} \text{S1}(t)+\text{k1} \text{S2}(t)-M \text{S1r}(t)-M \text{S2r}(t)+\text{m1} \text{S1}''(t)+\text{m1} \text{S2}''(t)=\text{f1}(t)$$

$$\left(\text{K2} \text{S1r}(t)+M \text{S1r}''(t)\right)+\left(\text{K2} \text{S2r}(t)+M \text{S2r}''(t)\right)-\text{m1} \text{S1}(t)-\text{$\alpha $2} \text{m1} \text{S2}(t)=0$$

$$\text{$\alpha $1} \text{k1} \text{S1}(t)+\text{$\alpha $2} \text{k1} \text{S2}(t)-\text{$\alpha $3} M \text{S1r}(t)-\text{$\alpha $4} M \text{S2r}(t)+\text{$\alpha $1} \text{m1} \text{S1}''(t)+\text{$\alpha $2} \text{m1} \text{S2}''(t)=\text{f2}(t)$$

$$\text{$\alpha $3} \left(\text{K2} \text{S1r}(t)+M \text{S1r}''(t)\right)+\text{$\alpha $4} \left(\text{K2} \text{S2r}(t)+M \text{S2r}''(t)\right)-\text{$\alpha $1} \text{m1} \text{S1}(t)-\text{$\alpha $2} \text{$\alpha $2} \text{m1} \text{S2}(t)=0$$

So I am looking to find $$\text{S1}(t)+\text{S2}(t)$$  $$\text{$\alpha $1} \text{S1}(t)+\text{$\alpha $2} \text{S2}(t)$$ $$\text{S1r}(t)+\text{S2r}(t)$$ $$\text{$\alpha $3} \text{S1r}(t)+\text{$\alpha $4} \text{S2r}(t)$$